# Troubleshooting why a program closes after disconnecting RDP

Tags: remote-desktop

I use RDP to run a program (ANSYS Fluent) on two headless workstations (win7 and Win10). If I disconnect (not log off) from the RDP session Fluent is immediately closed. However, all other programs (even other ANSYS programs) continue to run without problems.

How can I troubleshoot this problem? Is there a way to log all commands such that I could disconnect the RDP, reconnect and view what is actually happening during that time?

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/remote-desktop-connection-does-not-leave-programs/f29719e9-64d2-4614-b66c-2363511a9293

> Open **gpedit.msc**
>
> Browse to **Computer Configuration** --> **Administrative Templates** --> **Windows Components** --> **Remote Desktop Services** --> **Remote Desktop Session Host** --> **Session Time Limits**.
>
> Enable the "**Set time limit for disconnected sessions**" and set it to "**Never**".
>
> [I didn't have to do this [next step] but here for completeness]
>
> and change the **Local Security Policy** under **Local Policies** -> **Security Options** -> **Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+Del**" to "**Enabled**", the problem disappears.

Comment: Yes, I tried many of those MS suggestions yesterday. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to solve anything. The thing that surprises me is that it's only one specific program that terminates, not all of them.